# How to determine the parameter types of a method in java?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to check if parameter has a specific type. For example

```
public void foo (int a, String b){

}
```

How do I determine if method `foo` has a first parameter of type `int` and second `String`? So far I've only found how to check the types for variables but not for parameters, and I also came across generic class and stuff. Is there a easy way of doing what I am asking?

Can anyone do a quick demo on how reflection works in this case? I am very confused!

Comment: You can see it right in the definition of the function...? Do you mean at runtime?

Comment: Are you talking about finding the parameter types during runtime? If so check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Comment: yes. Like if I were to call the function in main how do I determine the types?